# How to read the data from HTML file and write the data to CSV file using python?

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

I have a .html file report which consists of the data in terms of tables and pass-fail criteria. so I want this data to be written to .csv file Using Python3.
Please suggest me how to proceed?
For example, the data will be like this:

```
<h2>Sequence Evaluation of Entire Project &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<em class="contentlink"><a href="#contents">[Contents]</a></em> </h2>

<table width="100%" class="coverage">
  <tr class="nohover">
    <td colspan="8" class="tableabove">Test Sequence State</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" style="white-space:nowrap;">Metric</th>
    <th colspan="2">Percentage</th>
    <th>Target</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Reached</th>
    <th>Unreached</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Test Sequence Work Progress</td>
    <td>100.0%</td>
    <td>
      <table class="metricbar">
        <tr class="borderX">
          <td class="white"></td>
          <td class="target"></td>
          <td class="white" colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="covreached" width="99%"></td>
          <td class="target" width="1%"></td>
          <td class="covreached" width="0%"></td>
          <td class="covnotreached" width="0%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="borderX">
          <td class="white"></td>
          <td class="target"></td>
          <td class="white" colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>100%</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
```

Comment: What kind of data ? Anyway you should have a look at the Python [standard lib](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: Parse the HTML using either `re` or `BeautifulSoup` libraries, extract the table rows and cells, store that in some data structure, and at the end write into CSV using `pandas` or standard python libs.

Comment: It's nice you added the html, but it's still unclear *what* you want to extract from there.

Comment: from <td colspan="2">Test Sequence Work Progress</td> I want,"Test Sequence Work Progress" as column heading and <td>100.0%</td> as the value as 100% in .csv file...

Comment: @SupratimHaldar please do NOT recommand using regexps to parse HTML - regexps cannot properly parse a language with arbitrarily nested structures. Also, you definitly don't need panda to write a csv file, the stdlib's csv module is perfectly able to do so (FWIW panda uses it under the hood so the only thing you get is useless dependencies and overhead).

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers for the suggestions, these are good information!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know header and really only need the associated percentage, with bs4 4.7.1 you can use :contains to target header and then take next `td`. You would be reading your HTML from file into html variable shown.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

html = '''
<h2>Sequence Evaluation of Entire Project &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<em class="contentlink"><a href="#contents">[Contents]</a></em> </h2>

<table width="100%" class="coverage">
  <tr class="nohover">
    <td colspan="8" class="tableabove">Test Sequence State</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" style="white-space:nowrap;">Metric</th>
    <th colspan="2">Percentage</th>
    <th>Target</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Reached</th>
    <th>Unreached</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Test Sequence Work Progress</td>
    <td>100.0%</td>
    <td>
      <table class="metricbar">
        <tr class="borderX">
          <td class="white"></td>
          <td class="target"></td>
          <td class="white" colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="covreached" width="99%"></td>
          <td class="target" width="1%"></td>
          <td class="covreached" width="0%"></td>
          <td class="covnotreached" width="0%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="borderX">
          <td class="white"></td>
          <td class="target"></td>
          <td class="white" colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>100%</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  '''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml') # 'html.parser' if lxml not installed
header = 'Test Sequence Work Progress'
result = soup.select_one('td:contains("' + header + '") + td').text
df = pd.DataFrame([result], columns = [header])
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Comment: you forgot to import pandas up there :)
```import pandas as pd```

Comment: @nexla Thanks. The hazards of using jupyter!

Comment: Thank you for this answer but I have Bs4 version 4.6.0

Comment: I would recommend upgrading as there is a lot of improvement and more functionality in 4.7.1

Comment: I don't know whether nth-of-type is supported in your version but you could try changing selector to .coverage td:nth-of-type(2)

Comment: result = soup.select_one(.coverage td:nth-of-type(2)).text   Try that otherwise (with caveat of implementation)

Comment: panda is totally useless here, the stdlib's csv module is all the OP need.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It is not totally useless. It is simply a different approach. The real focus however was the css selector.

Comment: @QHarr it _is_ totally useless - it doesn't require much more code to use the csv module directly so all you get are overhead (panda uses the csv module) and dependencies for no good reason.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I think it is your use of language. Useless means serves no purpose - not that it is not optimal

Comment: @QHarr "serves no purpose" is a perfectly correct definition here: it's not needed  and doesn't improve the code nor the perfs, so as far as I'm concerned it doesn't serve any purpose indeed. Note that I can see the point of - and totally agree with - choosing BS4 over the stlib's parser (to support incorrect markup and make data retrieval easier) or to use `requests` instead of the stlib's http features (better API, makes the code much simpler to write and maintain).

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

out = open('out.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
path="my.html"  #add the path of your local file here


soup = BeautifulSoup(open(path), 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('p'): #add tag whichyou want to extract
 a=link.get_text()
 out.write(a)
out.write('\n')
out.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,can I open a html file(not any URL i have) so if I open the html,read it and then iterate that in for loop,will this work?

Comment: Yes, It will work , Just enter the relative path correctly !

Comment: still working on it,but in my requirement I don't need the excel,could you tell me why you have written in excel please?

Comment: Okay ! Let me know if you face any problem

Comment: I needed it for excel , That's why, but it's quite easy to convert xls to csv

Comment: Should I write it for CSV ? If you need let me know

Comment: Yes please.. it will be very helpful.

Comment: Okay wait, I'll do it for you

Comment: I updated the answer ,Just check it once and let me know if it works !

Comment: Thank you very much for your update,here I want to use the .html file from my existing path instead of urls ,so I'm trying to change that part by opening a html file but struck with requests package,getting error for line  "page = requests.get(i)"

Comment: Hi Harini ! I updated it for local html files, I hope this time it will work as you have expected